# how can I combine well php and html in this code?

Tags: php, html

I have a query that returns me a long series of questions and answers. in my html page I have div that alternate with slider effect. so far everything is fine. at the moment I try to correctly display a question from the db bumps everything. why?

```
<div align=Center>
        <br/>
            <h1><?php echo  $rowfirst['Cognome']." ".$rowfirst['Nome']; ?></h1>
            <br/>
        <div class="nivo-slider">
            <div class="navigation"></div>
          <?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
?>

            <div id="nivo">
                <div class="element" align=Center><h3>Anamnesi pregressa</h3>
                  <table class="w3-table w3-bordered " style="width:400px;padding:10px;" align="center">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                  <th scope="row"><?php echo  $row['testo'];}?></th>
                  <td>risposta 1</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

                </div>

                <div class="element" align=Center><h3>Scrittura</h3>
              <table class="w3-table w3-bordered" style="width:400px;padding:10px;" align="center">
                <tbody>

                  <tr>
              <th scope="row">domanda 1</th>
              <td>risposta 1</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
                <div class="element"><h3>Motricità</h3>
              <table class="w3-table w3-bordered " style="width:400px;padding:10px;" align="center">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
              <th scope="row">domanda 1</th>
              <td>risposta 1</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>

            </div>

      <br/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The problem is the while. cycle. how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: I have no error messages but the slider no  works.

Comment: Is `<div id="nivo">` part of the slider's container? Maybe that should be outside the `while` loop. Otherwise, it seems it will generate duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

What you have will create malformed HTML.

In order to prevent malformed HTML, you should place your while () { and } where the tags matches like I have done with <tr> and </tr> shown below:

```
<?php
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
?>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"><?php echo  $row['testo'];?></th>
              <td>risposta 1</td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

That will fix your malformed HTML but the while statement may or may not be in the right place and without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve you'll have to correct it from there. As for the slider you mentioned, you probably need to supply more information if this answer doesn't solve your issue.